# Error generating route "undefined": This page could not be found

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, netlify-cms

Hei, I am creating a website with Nuxt and netlify cms when I run `npm run generate` it gives the error :

```js
√ Generated route "/about"                                                                            10:03:26  

 ERROR  Error generating route "undefined": This page could not be found                              10:03:26  

√ Generated route "/"
```

Then in my `/dist` folder  I have an undefined folder. I can't figure it out where it comes from...I have deleted the folder and generate again, and it creates the folder again.
If I go to the folder `undefined` inside there is an `index.html` files with the title " This page could not be found"...
Can someone share some light please? much appreaciated

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an pretty old issue, but I stumbled upon a similar issue when using a link to a statically generated admin interface in Nuxt:

```
<a href='/admin'>...</a>
```

Nuxt is using a [Crawler](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#crawler) that scans for relative links and matches them with your dynamic ones. Since admin is not a Nuxt page I use, it was throwing the same error. The solution is to either set the crawler `false` or exclude the relative link it should ignore. In your `nuxt.config.js` do:

```
generate: {
    // crawler: false, or:
    exclude: ['/admin']
}
```

I can imagine in your case, you were using a relative link on an `<a>` tag with some kind of computed variable, maybe `<a :href='link'>` where link was actually undefined, which would let the crawler search for a `'undefined'` page under your `pages` folder, causing the error. Just for anyone that lands here and still doesn't have a solution!